# Viewing and capturing real time values of Electronic balance measuring instrument on television set and computer monitor larger screens

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electronic-configuration, teaching-lab

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_scale

Is it possible to view and capture real time values of Electronic balance measuring instrument using wired, wireless,CCTV technology on television set or computer monitor larger screens?

Scenario

Chemistry labs - Electronic balance interfaced wired/wireless with the television set or computer monitor i.e.Larger display screen display taking into account.Viewing the mass recording of a object in real time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about chemistry.

Comment: At my local big box store one can readily find wireless home security camera sets, often with up to 8 cameras or more, and a regular monitor. Includes ability to select one or all cameras on the display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three possibilities come to mind:

(1) Purchase a scale with a digital output e.g, https://www.arlynscales.com/digital-indicator/industrial-scales-with-analog-and-digital-outputs/ , send it to your computer, and output it to a monitor (depending on the scale's output format, it may be possible to send it directly from the scale to a monitor)

(2) Point a USB webcam towards the scale's digital readout, plug that into to your computer, and then display on a monitor.

(3) Same as no. 2, but use a digital camcorder that has a digital output that can be displayed directly on a monitor, without the need for a computer.

Comment: Thanks. Same above solutions are applicable also to Television set ?

Comment: Depends on the type of video input formats your TV can recieve.  You'd need to check your TV.